Flutter - How to ensure sub-pages inherit the intended theme data?
Different parts of my app require different themes. My assumption was that flutter would apply the nearest ThemeData it finds up the widget tree and apply that theme. But this doesn't seem to work when navigating to new pages.
For example, in the below code I would have expected both SecondRoute and ThirdRoute to use the ThemeData provided in the FirstRoute. But actually only SecondRoute uses the specified ThemeData, and ThirdRoute uses the ThemeData specified in MyApp.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

        /// Default ThemeData specified here:
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
          primaryColor: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: const FirstRoute());
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("FirstRoute"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>

                      /// New ThemeData specified here:
                      Theme(
                          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                            primaryColor: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                          child: const SecondRoute())),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Go To SecondRoute",
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("SecondRoute"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ThirdRoute()),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Go To ThirdRoute",
            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "ThirdRoute",
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Lorem Ipsum",
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

My desired result is that all sub-pages inherit the new theme data.
What would be the best solution for this? Should I use a second MaterialApp instead of a Theme widget so that all its children inherit its theme? Or would doing that create other problems? Should I instead include a Theme widget in each subpage and define the theme data for each one? Something else?

let me guess the new theme is applied for the second screen only? the third one has the original theme?
